# Эффект «волны» при клике на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animation

Как создать эффект «волны» при клике на кнопку?

Comment: Это можно сделать на css, если подойдёт конечно ))

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1002419/188366

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Написал несколько скриптов, которые анимируют волну с места клика и работают в `Safari`.

#### Вариант 1: одна волна

При первом клике создаётся один элемент с волной, который остаётся в DOM. При повторном клике до окончания анимации волна прерывается и начинается заново.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button')

btns.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        let
            size = Math.max(this.offsetWidth, this.offsetHeight),
            x = e.offsetX - size / 2,
            y = e.offsetY - size / 2,
            wave = this.querySelector('.wave')

        // Create an element if it doesn't exist
        if (!wave) {
            wave = document.createElement('span')
            wave.className = 'wave'
        }
        wave.style.cssText = `width:${size}px;height:${size}px;top:${y}px;left:${x}px`
        this.appendChild(wave)
    })
})
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #232323;
  padding: 0 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 700 18px/46px 'Arial';
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .25s;
}

button:hover {
  background: #444;
}

.wave {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: wave .5s linear;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes wave {
  100% {
   transform: scale(2);
   opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Кнопка</button>
```

#### Вариант 2: несколько волн

При каждом клике создаётся новый элемент с волной, который удаляется из DOM после завершения анимации. Таким образом, при повторном клике до окончания предыдущей анимации она не прерывается.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button')

btns.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        const
            size = Math.max(this.offsetWidth, this.offsetHeight),
            x = e.offsetX - size / 2,
            y = e.offsetY - size / 2,
            wave = document.createElement('span')

        // Create a new wave
        wave.className = 'wave'
        wave.style.cssText = `width:${size}px;height:${size}px;top:${y}px;left:${x}px`
        this.appendChild(wave)

        // Remove element after animation ends
        setTimeout(() => wave.remove(), 500)
    })
})
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #232323;
  padding: 0 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 700 18px/46px 'Arial';
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .25s;
}

button:hover {
  background: #444;
}

.wave {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: wave .5s linear;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes wave {
  100% {
   transform: scale(2);
   opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: Ваш метод тоже не идеален и не  работает на Safari, http://recordit.co/THFbXJLGQM , мне тоже минуснуть ваш ответ ?

Comment: Хахаха. Серьезно?) Вы проверяете в браузере 2012 года на Windows? Мой ответ правильно работает в последних 5 версиях Safari. А ваш - даже в 11.1 не работает.

Comment: наверно удалить надо span ?

Comment: @MaximLensky отработанный span удаляется при следующем клике.

Comment: я думал ваще удалить - так как он остаётся

Comment: @MaximLensky зачем лишние манипуляции c DOM?

Comment: это же не лишние - его же в разметке нету в button а появляется только после клика ... наверно [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event) удалить можно

Comment: @MaximLensky вы хотите вообще удалить span? Так собственно span – это и есть волна.

Comment: да я не спорю - я вижу что там span делает - я про то что его же нет в разметке

Comment: плюс то я поставил - мне понравился ваш ответ

Comment: @MaximLensky я просто не пойму, зачем удалять span после срабатывания анимации? Он всё равно невидимый. А после следующей итерации будет создан новый span. Разве, что можно span сразу вставлять в разметку, а по клику выставлять координаты. Но тогда при разработке неудобно руками прописывать его каждый раз.

Comment: так то да ... у меня было как то такое - я тоже так же создал инлайновый элемент и и делал анимашку - это было тестовое задание при устройстве на работу - а удалить не удалил после анимации - и это была критическая ошибка - мне отказали

Comment: @MaximLensky понял вас. Но в программировании я пытаюсь следовать принципам YAGNI и KISS.

Comment: простите я не знаю что это такое

Comment: @MaximLensky https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI и https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF)

Comment: @MaximLensky переделал скрипт, чтобы на повторный клик span не удалялся, а у него просто обновлялись координаты.

Comment: я два раза нажать на палец вверх не могу - круто как обычно ...

Answer (score 12):

Приведу пример на `CSS`:

```css
button{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 22px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  background: #167dad;
}

button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: scale(1, 1) translate(-50%);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(25, 25);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(40, 40);
  }
}

button:focus:not(:active)::after {
  animation: ripple 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button>Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: классно получилось , я такое делал только на :focus от меня плюсик

Comment: В Safari не работает.

Comment: @Vadizar какая версия Safari ?

Comment: Версия 11.1 (13605.1.33.1.2)

Comment: для сафари нужен :focus

Comment: В Safari 13 до сих пор не работает ))