# hover/focus эффект кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Пример]

Как можно реализовать такой эффект?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96145/discussion-on-question-by-roman-hover-focus--).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/810826/Стилизация-волны-в-кнопке-при-клике

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так, наверное, двигаем радиальный градиент:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let s;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  function draw(t) {
    t - (s = s || t) < 1000 && requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    t = (t - s) / 500
    let r = b.getBoundingClientRect();
    let p = `${e.x - r.x} ${e.y - r.y},${t * Math.max(r.width, r.height)}`;
    b.style.backgroundImage=`-webkit-gradient(radial,${p},${p},from(rgba(255,255,255,${0.6-t*0.6})),to(#fff0))`
  }
}))
```

```css
.btn {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #999;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    transition: 300ms;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.btn.btn-green:hover {
    background-color: #00c853;
}

.btn.btn-red:hover {
    background-color: #c80000;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-green">Зеленая кнопка</button>
<button class="btn btn-red">Красная кнопка</button>
```

Comment: Вы как будто Material Design никогда не видели :) Скорее всего имеется в виду [что-то такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6aQF.gif) (впрочем, автор не уточнил, что он имеет в виду)

Comment: @andreymal подпилил =)