# Эффект по кнопке от мышки при клике (jQuery) Как?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, css3, html5

Я не знаю как называется такой эффект но при клике на кнопку\ссылку (тег короче) нужно что бы по кнопке от мышки проходил эффект заполнения кнопки от мышки до краёв

Пример: ютуб, кнопка войти ы ютубе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по кнопке постепенно от клика до краёв идёт заполнение
ещё пример, десктопная версия телеграма, там почти все кнопки сделаны так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

кругом как бы заполняется кнопка
есть один весьма наглядный пример - https://dwstroy.ru/lessons/les3601/demo/index.html#

нужно примерно так но что бы круг-волна не перекрывал текст и не делать hover
я честно понятия не имею как это можно реализовать

так же обязательно что бы эффект происходил при клике мышкой но не при отрыве мышки после клика

именно такие кнопки предлагает материал ui но мне нужен пример чистой реализации

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1002419/188366

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [hover/focus эффект кнопки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1002406/hover-focus-%d1%8d%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/810826/Стилизация-волны-в-кнопке-при-клике

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.waves', function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) return;

    const offset = $(this).offset();

    const eventX = e.pageX - offset.left;
    const eventY = e.pageY - offset.top;

    const diameter = Math.min(this.offsetHeight, this.offsetWidth, 50);

    const ripple = $('<div/>', {class: "wavesWrapper", appendTo: $(this)});

    $('<div/>', {
        class: "wavesEffect",
        css: {
            width: diameter,
            height: diameter,
            left: eventX - (diameter / 2),
            top: eventY - (diameter / 2),
        },
        appendTo: ripple,
        one: {
            animationend: function () {
                ripple.remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 18px 40px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 10px;
 user-select: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.btn.btn-dark {
 background-color: #2c3e50;
 color: #fff;
}

.btn.btn-red {
 background-color: #e74c3c;
 color: #fff;
}

.btn.btn-blue {
 background-color: #3498db;
}

.btn.btn-block {
 display: block;
}

.waves {
 position: relative;
}

.waves .wavesWrapper {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 transform: translateZ(0);
 border-radius: inherit;
 pointer-events: none;
 animation: waves-shadow 2s ease;
}

.waves .wavesEffect {
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 50%;
 transform: scale(0.7);
 background-color: #e74c3c;
 opacity: 0.4;
 animation: waves 2s;
}

.waves.waves-dark .wavesEffect {
 background-color: #000;
}

.waves.waves-light .wavesEffect {
 background-color: #fff;
}

.waves.waves-darken .wavesEffect {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.waves.waves-without-shadow .wavesWrapper {
 animation: none;
}

@keyframes waves-shadow {
 0% {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
 }

 20% {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 }

 100% {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
 }
}

@keyframes waves {
 to {
  transform: scale(10);
  opacity: 0;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="btn btn-dark waves waves-light">BUTTON</div>
 <div class="btn btn-red waves waves-dark">BUTTON</div>
 <div class="btn waves">BUTTON</div>
 <div class="btn btn-block btn-dark waves waves-light">BUTTON</div>
 <div class="btn btn-block btn-red waves waves-dark">BUTTON</div>
 <div class="btn btn-block waves">BUTTON</div>
</div>
```

Я давно делал вот так.

Прикладываю SASS: [CodeOpen](https://codepen.io/molof/pen/XWWVLdm)

**.wavesWrapper** - обертка.
**.wavesEffect** - сам эффект, круг.

**.wavesWrapper animataion** - анимация тени на элементе, можно убрать.
**.wavesEffect animation** - анимация увеличения круга, можно ускорить или замедлить анимацию, плюс можно в **@keyframes** увеличить размер **scale()** чтобы круг покрывал элемент полностью.

Да вроде там в примере все есть, некоторые заделки под разные цвета, поэтому кастомизируйте под себя.

Comment: Как вынести текст выше эффекта, что бы круги не лезли на текст? За ответ спасибо большое

Comment: @DmitryDevelop , в кнопку поместите span или p, задайте им positio: relative; и z-index: 1; и у вас текст будет всегда за слоем с кругами

Answer (score 2):

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('butt'),
  forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

forEach.call(buttons, function(b) {
  b.addEventListener('click', addElement);
});

function addElement(e) {
  var addDiv = document.createElement('div'),
    mValue = Math.max(this.clientWidth, this.clientHeight),
    rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  sDiv = addDiv.style,
    px = 'px';

  sDiv.width = sDiv.height = mValue + px;
  sDiv.left = e.clientX - rect.left - (mValue / 2) + px;
  sDiv.top = e.clientY - rect.top - (mValue / 2) + px;

  addDiv.classList.add('pulse');
  this.appendChild(addDiv);
}
```

```css
.dws {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.butt {
  border: 3px solid #218294;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #218294;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  transition: .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.butt::before,
.butt::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #218294;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: .3s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.butt::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: .2s;
}

.butt:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.butt:hover::before,
.butt:hover::after {
  left: 0;
}

.pulse {
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: pulse 0.7s ease-out;
  transform: scale(0);
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  to {
    transform: scale(2);
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dws">
  <a href="#" class="butt">button</a>
</div>
```