# Анимация с места клика

Tags: html, css, css3, анимация, css-animation

Как мне сделать так, чтобы анимация происходила именно на месте клика? Мне нужно, чтобы при клике блок не сразу закрашивался белым цветом, а анимация закрашивания блока начиналась с места клика, распространяясь на весь блок в виде волны, и после этого сразу же возвращался обратно красный цвет. Вот мой код:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 1px #999;
  background-color: red;
}

.block:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block:active {
  background-color: white;
}

#num {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="block">
    <p id="num">1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p id="num">2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p id="num">3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1002419/188366

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Стилизация «волны» в кнопке при клике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/810826/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Источник: https://geeklaunch.net/button-ripple-effect/index.html

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function(b) {
  b.addEventListener('click', createRipple);
});

function createRipple(e) {
  var circle = document.createElement('div');
  this.appendChild(circle);

  var d = Math.max(this.clientWidth, this.clientHeight);

  circle.style.width = circle.style.height = d + 'px';

  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  circle.style.left = e.clientX - rect.left - d / 2 + 'px';
  circle.style.top = e.clientY - rect.top - d / 2 + 'px';


  circle.classList.add('ripple');

  let animated = document.querySelector('.ripple');

  animated.onanimationend = () => {
    animated.remove();
  };

}
```

```css
button {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0.15em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

button .ripple {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: ripple 0.6s linear;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  to {
    transform: scale(2.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>ripple effects</button>
<button>ripple effects</button>
<button>ripple effects</button>
<button>ripple effects</button>
<button>ripple effects</button>
```

Comment: По поводу удаления DIV-a - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event + `remove()`

Comment: у нас с Вами один часовой пояс ;-) Торопиться некуда - говорят, что есть вероятность продления "коронаотпуска" до мая ((

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".block").mousedown(function(e) {
    var puls = $(this).find(".puls");
    puls.removeClass("animate");
    var x = parseInt(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) - (puls.width() / 2);
    var y = parseInt(e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) - (puls.height() / 2);
    puls.css({
      top: y,
      left: x
    }).addClass("animate");
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 1px #999;
  background-color: red;
  user-select: none;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}

.block:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#num {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.puls {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.animate {
  animation: puls 0.7s linear;
}

@keyframes puls {
  100% {
    background-color: white;
    transform: scale(20);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="block">
    <p id="num">1</p>
    <div class="puls"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p id="num">2</p>
    <div class="puls"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p id="num">3</p>
    <div class="puls"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: JQuery в 2020 году?

Comment: @Vadizar, и в 20-м, и в 21, и даже в 25-м.

Comment: Зачем, если это пишется нативно? Короче и меньше вычислений. А юзать лишние зависимости – это бессмысленные вычисления. Из-за этого растёт энтропия. Больше выброса углерода в атмосферу.